# Get the subsite list of a sharepoint site with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sharepoint

Do you know how I could retrieve all sub-sites from my sharepoint site and put them in a list? I thought I could do it using `this.context.pageContext` but I did not find it. Sorry if my question looks obvious, I am new to typescript.

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...
using JSOM and TypeScript you need to get current context, then site collection object, and from there AllWebs collection (with included Title property)

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var allWebs = context.get_site().get_allWebs();
context.load(allWebs, 'Include(Title)');
var list = new Array();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeeded, failed);

function succeeded(sender, args) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allWebs.get_count(); i++) {
        var subWeb = webSubSites.itemAt(i);                 
        array.push(subWeb.get_title());
    }
}
function failed(sender, args) {
    console.log(args);
}
```

This is plain javascript but if you would to benefit from TypeScript you could use sharepoint.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharepoint.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)

Then you could define your callbacks (success, failed) as fallows:

```
function succeeded(sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs) {
    // code here
}
function failed(sender: any, args: SP.ClientRequestFailedEventArgs) {
    // code here
}
```